# attach event handler to dynamically added element

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code, which adds an element dynamically and event handler to it.
this event handler is called (and vanishes) when the element is added.
when I see the dynamically added element through inspector(to see if the event handler was added successfully or not) I can't find `onchnage="texttol(eletext)"` function added it it.

```
eletext  = document.createElement("input");
eletext.type="text";
eletext.placeholder = "Type Here";
eletext.onchange=texttol(eletext);
event.target.appendChild(eletext);
```

Comment: JQuery uses `.live()` instead of `.on()` to address the situation that you describe. Even if you are not using JQuery, you could look at how it is implemented.

Comment: Assigning the `onchange` property does not change the `onchange` attribute in the DOM.

Comment: @Felix, `live` has been deprecated for some time now. Event delegation would be appropriate. That said, this question doesn't have jQuery tagged, so it's not an appropriate answer.

Comment: @zzzzBov - that's why I made it as comment; not an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add your event handling once the element is actually in the DOM.

```js
var eletext = document.createElement("input");
eletext.type = "text";
eletext.placeholder = "Type Here";
eletext.id = "eletext";
document.body.appendChild(eletext);

eletext.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  texttol(eletext.value);
}, false);

function texttol(str) {
  alert('texttol function passes: ' + str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With this line, you are calling the method texttol and attaching whatever it returns to the event handler.

```
eletext.onchange=texttol(eletext);
```

You need to use a closure

```
eletext.onchange = function() { texttol(eletext) };
```

even better, use addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue but the mentioned solutions do not work.
The event handler function theme_onChange is executed on adding each element.

I have a Bootstrap dropdwn menu (#themeDropdownMenu) and want to fill it dynamically with button elements via looping over the "Themes" object properties.

```js
function setThemes () {
 var lstThemes = document.querySelector('#themeDropdownMenu');
 var newItem;
 
 for ( x in Themes ) {
  newItem = document.createElement('button');
  newItem.innerHTML = x;
  newItem.classList.add('dropdown-item');
  newItem.type='button';
  lstThemes.appendChild(newItem);
  newItem.addEventListener('click', theme_onChange(newItem) );
 }
}

function theme_onChange (item) {
 /* console.log("Theme: " + item.innerHTML); */
 console.log (item);
}
```

Result:
console logs each added button element.

Comment: My fault. The problem was the parameter thas was passed to the event handler funcction. The parameter must be removed then it works.

Comment: the solution eletext.onchange = function() { texttol(eletext) };, was something that i used and it is working well